# How can I get all employees with a salary less than the average salary?

Tags: sql

I can get the count of employees and avg salary but when I try to get the the addition select of listing the number of employees paid below the average it fails.

```
select count(employee_id),avg(salary) 
from employees
Where salary < avg(salary);
```

Comment: I think you need a HAVING clause instead of a WHERE clause.

Comment: Please use real English sentences rather than the rambling list of keywords your title was originally composed of.

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*), (select avg(salary) from employees)
from employees 
where salary < (select avg(salary) from employees);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `AVG` is an aggregation function.  SQL is not smart enough to figure out how to mix aggregated results within the rows.  The traditional way is to use a join:

```
select count(*), avg(e.salary),
        sum(case when e.salary < const.AvgSalary then 1 else 0 end) as NumBelowAverage
from employees e cross join
     (select avg(salary) as AvgSalary from employees) as const
```

Comment: +1 you could also use the cross join as a filter and a simple count(*) in this particular case as the OP hasn't asked for a count of the total number of employees.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select TotalNumberOfEmployees,
          AverageSalary,
          count(e.employee_id) NumberOfEmployeesBelowAverageSalary
     from (
            select count(employee_id) TotalNumberOfEmployees,
                   avg(salary) AverageSalary
              from employees
          ) preagg
left join employees e on e.salary < preagg.AverageSalary
 group by TotalNumberOfEmployees,
          AverageSalary
```

Note: I used a LEFT join so if you had 3 equal employees, it would show 0 instead of no results (nobody below below average).

Comment: +1 though I'm still trying to work out if there is a sensible way of doing this with windowing functions ;)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear which columns you want in your result set, which makes it difficult to answer your question.  Making the question clear improves the quality of the answers.

You seem to want 3 facts:

1. Number of employees.
2. Average salary.
3. Number of employees earning less than the average salary.

And you show a query which does the job for the first two facts:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEmployees,
       AVG(Salary) AS AverageSalary
  FROM Employees
```

What's the difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(Employee_ID)`?  The difference is that the latter only counts the rows where there is a non-NULL value in the Employee_ID column.  A good optimizer will recognize that Employee_ID is a primary key and contains no NULL values, and the query will be the same.  But `COUNT(*)` is more conventional and less reliant on the optimizer.

The other statistic can be generated as a simple value in the select-list via a sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEmployees,
       AVG(Salary) AS AverageSalary,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Employees
         WHERE Salary < (SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM Employees)
       ) AS NumberOfEmployeesPaidSubAverageWages
  FROM Employees
```

Under many circumstances, it would not be appropriate to write the sub-query like that, but for the interpretation of the specified query, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from <table name> where salary < (select avg(<salary column name) from <table name>);
```

Example:

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where sal < (select avg(emp_sal) from EMPLOYEE);
```

Comment: You should elaborate your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ename,e.deptno,e.sal,d.avg
FROM emp e,(SELECT deptno, avg(sal) avg
             FROM emp
             GROUP BY deptno) d
 WHERE e.deptno=d.deptno
 AND
 e.sal < d.avg
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Also, while this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!